# redirect to different route if input was submitted - React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a React Application for searching for movies using the OMDb.

My app works in two stages:

- You are presented initially with a search box
- Upon submitting the search box with a movie query, the app should redirect to a results page.

Below is my Main application:

```
class Muuvies extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state ={
            movies: [],
            error: "",
            searchedFor: "",
        };

        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    }

    search({data}) {
        fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${OMDB_API_KEY}&s=${data}&type=movie`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        }).then(json => this.setState({
            searchedFor: data,
            movies: propOr([], 'Search', json),
            error: json.Error
        })).catch(err => this.setState({
            error: 'Error Occurred: Try Again',
            movies: [],
            searchedFor: ''
        }));

        // if there wasn't an error, redirect to the Results page, passing what is returned from fetch().
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Logo role="img" aria-label="search"></Logo>
            <SearchWrapper>
                <Search search={this.search} />
                {
                    this.state.error
                    ? <Error><span role="img" aria-label="error" style={{marginRight: 2 + 'px'}}>⚠️</span>{this.state.error}</Error>
                    : null
                }
            </SearchWrapper>
        </Container>
    );
    }
}
```

How do I change my application so, that if the user submits the form and there isn't an error (e.g. `this.state.error` is empty after the `fetch()`), then it redirects them to the `Results` component?

Contents of `Search.js`:

```
class Search extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: '',
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.search(this.state);
    this.setState({ data: '' });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <StyledForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <StyledSearch id="data" type="text"
            name="data"
            placeholder="Search for Muuvies."
            value={path(['state', 'data'], this)}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            autoComplete="off"
            autoFocus={true}
        />
      </StyledForm>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history) has a method `push()` than you can use to programatically navigate. `history` should be available on the component's props.You'd need to use [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to access this.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky So, something like `if (!this.state.error) this.props.history.push(Results)`?

Comment: I'll create an answer to demonstrate, but can I ask why you'd have an error inside your `then()`?

Comment: I think you should ask yourself why you want `results` to be its own separate route. What is the point of that? Typically, you would not want a route in your application to depend upon the prior state of your app. What happens if someone goes directly to the `results` route of your app without having done a search? If you can't send someone a URL to a `results` route and have them do anything useful there, what is the point? Instead, maybe have just the `search` route and render the results there as needed.

Comment: For every route in your app, ask yourself "would my user be able to bookmark this in their browser? Will they be able to return to it in a later session, considering that React `state` will be lost? What will they see when they return to the bookmark and how will it be useful to them?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given you are using `react-router-dom` you can use [history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history)'s `push()` method. This would need to be used with wrapping component [withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) to expose the necessary props. This would also need to be done with `then()` do to the async nature of your API call/search:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Muuvies extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state ={
            movies: [],
            error: "",
            searchedFor: "",
        };

        this.search = this.search.bind(this);
    }

    search({data}) {
        fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${OMDB_API_KEY}&s=${data}&type=movie`)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
            return res;
        }).then(json => {
          // you may not need this if your are redirecting
          this.setState({
              searchedFor: data,
              movies: propOr([], 'Search', json),
              error: json.Error
          }, () => {
            this.props.history.push("/results"); // or whatever string path
          });
        }).catch(err => this.setState({
            error: 'Error Occurred: Try Again',
            movies: [],
            searchedFor: ''
        }));

        // this would execute before API call/search is complete, need to do it in then()
    }

    render() {
    return (
        <Container>
            <Logo role="img" aria-label="search"></Logo>
            <SearchWrapper>
                <Search search={this.search} />
                {
                    this.state.error
                    ? <Error><span role="img" aria-label="error" style={{marginRight: 2 + 'px'}}>⚠️</span>{this.state.error}</Error>
                    : null
                }
            </SearchWrapper>
        </Container>
    );
    }
} 

export default withRouter(Muuvies);
```

This is assuming you have a [Route](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route) defined for your `Results` component/path:

```
import Results from './path/to/Results';

// ...

<Route path="/results" component={Results} />
```

You could also use the [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component in `render()` method, perhaps based on some state values:

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

// ...

render() {
   // check for error and maybe some other flag(s) such as a boolean property
   if (!this.state.error && this.state.submitted && this.state.movies.length > 0) {
     return <Redirect to={{ pathname: '/results', state: { movies: this.state.movies } }} />
   }

   // else render form or error maybe
}
```

That being demonstrated, if you are planning to navigate at the component's level to "/results" or whatever the path may be, You probably wouldn't need to set state. You can pass state as a second argument to the `history.push(path, state)` method if necessary.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: This is great thanks, but how do I get react-router to route to the `Results.js` file?

Comment: Well, you have something like `<Route path="/results" component={Results} />` defined in your application right? You may need to share your `<Route />` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code here:

```
search({data}) {
    fetch(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=${OMDB_API_KEY}&s=${data}&type=movie`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
        return res;
    }).then(json => {
        this.setState({
           searchedFor: data,
           movies: propOr([], 'Search', json),
           error: json.Error
        });
        //------
        //Write your code here, because if you got there, then there was no error at none of the "then" above
        //Or if a success response can contain an error field, you can check it with an if statement
        //------
    }).catch(err => this.setState({
        error: 'Error Occurred: Try Again',
        movies: [],
        searchedFor: ''
    }));
```

The code depends of how are you structurating your project and which libraries are you using.